# Problem loading Stl in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone I am new to ROS and using Ros indigo with UBUNTU trusty
I tried to make a urdf with my own stl and tried to run in rviz(latest version), but it showed the following error.
I am posting the error and aunch file below.
kindly help.

The error is :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment
[joint_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 3003, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/xeon74/.ros/log/9a85b020-9749-11e6-b2c4-1cc1de334fec/joint_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/xeon74/.ros/log/9a85b020-9749-11e6-b2c4-1cc1de334fec/joint_state_publisher-2*.log
[ERROR] [1477025310.997172887]: Error retrieving file [file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl]: Couldn't open file /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl
[ERROR] [1477025311.011398727]: Could not load model 'file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1477025311.011543180]: Could not load model 'file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
```

and my Launch file is :

```
<launch>
    <arg name="model" />
    <!-- Parsing xacro and setting robot_description parameter -->
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find my_robot)/urdf/my_urdf.urdf" />
    <!-- Setting gui parameter to true for display joint slider -->
    <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
    <!-- Starting Joint state publisher node which will publish the joint values -->
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
    <!-- Starting robot state publish which will publish tf -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
    <!-- Launch visualization in rviz -->
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find my_robot)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
</launch>
```

---

Edit: Thanx for reply, I checked the file system and found the file `ls -la /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl`  . Also I have installed `joint_state_publisher` from ros.wiki site under the complete package installation.
May the error is due to the .STL and .stl formats. Kindly suggest a way to  correct this problems.

---

Edit2: Here's the output of the command

```
ls -la /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xeon74 xeon74 23784 Oct 20 17:59 /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl
```

regarding the confusion between .stl and .STL , I was saying since Linux works under case sensitive environment , so will there be any problem using .STL instead of .stl ???

---

Edit3: Sorry for the wait. I was on vacation. I actually figured out the problem . Actually the problem was due to the loading of the single link in rviz without any joints and in the launch file I launched the joint state controller. Due  to that , it was showing error. But after i put some joints in it , it was working fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246135/problem-loading-stl-in-rviz/) by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-10-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-22**:
Could you please *edit* your question next time when you have additional information? Please use answers only to *answer* the question. Comments for other discussion.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2016-11-05**:
Hi, I meet similar problem like you. I draw a model file using sketchup, and convert it to stl using mashlab. This model file can be displayed in gazebo but get this "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment" error when loading in rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [ERROR] [1477025310.997172887]: Error retrieving file [file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl]: Couldn't open file /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl
> ```

```
[ERROR] [1477025311.011398727]: Could not load model 'file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource file:///home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
```

The error basically tells you that RViz cannot find the file `/home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl`. Two things to make sure:

1. is there actually a file called `base_3.stl` inside the `/home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl` directory?
2. does the user that starts RViz have read permissions for `base_3.stl`?

In both cases the output of `ls -la /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl` should provide us with that information, so please add the output of that command to your question (*edit* it).

**note**: in most cases, Linux runs on top of a case-sensitive file system, which means that `file.STL` is not the same as `file.stl`. Make sure `base_3.stl` is not actually `base_3.STL`. This is a common problem with urdfs and meshes created under Windows, and then copied to your Linux installation.

---

I would actually be more worried about this error:

> ```
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment
> ```

```
[joint_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 3003, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/xeon74/.ros/log/9a85b020-9749-11e6-b2c4-1cc1de334fec/joint_state_publisher-2.log].
```

This points to a rather strange error inside the `joint_state_publisher`. Can you tell us how you installed `joint_state_publisher`: did you use the `deb` packages, or did you built things from sources?

---

Edit:

> I checked the file system and found the file `ls -la /home/xeon74/my_bot/src/my_robot/mesh/stl/base_3.stl`.

So, where is the output of that command? Please add it to your original question, by editing it.

> Also I have installed `joint_state_publisher` from ros.wiki site under the complete package installation.

Ok. Then please report the `joint_state_publisher` part of the error over at [ros/robot_model/issues](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues).

> May the error is due to the .STL and .stl formats.

I'm not sure what you mean by this. `.stl` and `.STL` are both file extensions commonly used by STL files. Are you saying that you have a `.STL` file but not the `.stl` file?

Additionally, please include a fragment of your urdf which loads the meshes (ie: the `<geometry><mesh filename="package://../base_3.stl"/></geometry>` lines).

---

Edit2:

> regarding the confusion between .stl and .STL , I was saying since Linux works under case sensitive environment , so will there be any problem using .STL instead of .stl ???

As I wrote earlier: if your files are actually using `.STL` (upper case), but your urdf specifies `.stl` (lower case) then it will not work. But from the output of `ls -al ..` it would appear that the file actually exists, so I'm doubtful that is the problem here. Unless you know something we don't.

---

Edit3:

> But after i put some joints in it , it was working fine.

Are you referring to the `joint_state_publisher` problem (`local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment`), or the mesh loading issue?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1